# ProgressDialog is not showing when one process in Thread is runnning

Tags: android, progressdialog

the following code works fine but the progress dialog is not showing, I want to show it when the process DownloadData() is running.

This activity is not the only and not the main.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.MyActivity);
        } 

    public void Download(View view) {

            final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);

            dialog.setTitle("Processing...");
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.show();


            Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                public void run () {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            DownloadData();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    });

                }

            });

            background.start();

        }

    }
```

Comment: because you create your `dialog` and show it, but in the next step you create your `background` Thread, which closes your `dialog` immediately. Moreover, try to use `AcyncTask` instead of `Thread`. There are the methods to handle such stuff

Comment: the thread doesn't know how much time `DownloadData();` needs to execute so it closed immediately, put your code from `DownloadData();` so we can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to dismiss the dialog almost immediately after you create it. What happens if you remove?

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

You should look into using AsyncTask when you download something. It's awesome for showing a progress dialog whilst downloading.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Yes it´s works, I remove ProgressDialog from the Thread, the progressDialog started to show up and then just disapear when the  DownloadData is finished and pass to the next activity.